# issue in Android keyboard overlap edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, overlapping

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
tools:context="com.demo.waypointstest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txt_visit_site"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/loginlogo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="#312f2f"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_16" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/signup"
        android:text="Free Sign up"
        android:textColor="#4f4d4d"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_13" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#696969"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" >
    </EditText>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_pass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#696969"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_login"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:text="LOG IN"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/log_right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_rem_fg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_pass"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_rem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Remember me"
            android:textColor="#3a3939"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_pass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/fgp"
            android:textColor="#3a3939"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_14" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_visit_site"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/site"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#5A6F5A"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_12" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

in Manifest file i set android:windowSoftInputMode property as

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**EDIT**

[image]

i want keyboard below of bottom text like which write `for more info visit`

but still keyboard overlap in my edittext any idea how can i solve it?

**EDIT 1**

[image]

Comment: have tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysVisible"?

Comment: Ya i tried adjustPan , but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I just removed `android:windowSoftInputMode="..."`

from manifest and it worked great.
Sorry for posting answer instead of comment due to less reputation :)

Comment: You mean to say i remove android:windowSoftInputMode="..." from menifest is it?

Comment: Yes thats what i did in the past and it worked

Comment: Waqar can you try my layout code because i make a change in menifest as per your suggestion but still overlap keyboard

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot with overlaped keyboard?

Comment: Waqar see my Edit 1 Portion in question

Comment: You mean when focus is in email field. `for more info visit` should also visible?

Comment: Yes it is also visible

Comment: Try wrapping your Layout in a scroll viewer and listen for focus change event of edittext. When it got the focus. call `scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` of scrollviewer

Comment: Can you put your code so i can get better idea what you say ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this . you need to set an android:windowSoftInputModeattribute to adjustResize in Manifest and put your layout(from root RelativeLayout ) inside a ScrollView.

```
<activity
  android:name="..."
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

See developer [docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) for more discussion.

Comment: See my edit potion of my question

Comment: Add this in your edittext .android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction"

Comment: See this link i change my layout code as per you r suggestion but still facing same problem so can you guide me what i make it wornge on it http://pastebin.com/rVAeitU7